Discrepancy between vm.nr_hugepages and HugePages_Total
My /etc/sysctl.conf have: vm.nr_hugepages = 20484
but (even after sysctl -p) I got:
[root@vm04-oracle-19c ~]# cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i hugepages
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:   18933
HugePages_Free:       46
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
[root@vm04-oracle-19c ~]#

Why this happen? HugePages_Total should be 20484
Current memory:
[opc@vm04-oracle-19c ~]$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           63Gi        41Gi       887Mi       7.2Gi        21Gi        14Gi
Swap:         7.8Gi       7.0Mi       7.8Gi


How much free memory you have on this machine?

The machine has 62gb

Astora, did you read my question?

Currently the machine has 14Gi available (see my edit)
